# F# List.append leads to a prepend

Tags: f#

I got a very strange problem when I started to learn F#. It is said that the method List.append will append the second list to the first list. I also have checked the source code. Thats true as it simply use a @ operator
[image: source code]
However, when I try to call this method. It turns out to prepend the second list.
[image: strange thing]

[image: strange output]
Could someone help explain that to me?

Answer (score 1):

You're applying parameters in different order. Look at the definition of operator `|>`:

```
let (|>) x f = f x
```

As you can see, it takes a value on the right and a function on the left, and applies the function to the value. From this, it's easy to see that your expression:

```
card |> List.append ["tyle"]
```

It's equivalent to:

```
List.append ["tyle"] card
```

So the result is exactly as expected: the list `card` appended to the list `["tyle"]`

---

P.S. In the future, please post program code as text, not as pictures. Pictures are not searchable, so your question is much less likely to help somebody else with a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice and solution

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you consider accepting it? To do so, clock the grey checkmark to the left of the answer.